# Adding a geom_line to all facets in a facet_wrap plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I'm trying to create a `facet_wrap` plot that compares four separate lines to a common fifth line; the goal is to have this fifth line appearing on all four of the other `facet_wrap` plots.

Here's my minimal code:

```
library(ggplot2)

x    = c( 1,  3,  1,  3,  2,  4,  2,  4)
y    = c( 1,  3,  2,  4,  1,  3,  2,  4)
type = c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D")
data = data.frame(x,y,type)

x    = c( 4,  1)
y    = c( 1,  4)
type = c("E","E")
line = data.frame(x,y,type)

ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~type) +
geom_line(data = line, aes(x,y))
```

I was hoping that adding the fifth line as an independent `data.frame` would allow me to do this, but it just adds it as a fifth facet, as in the following image:

[image: Bad facet plot]

I want the "E" facet to show up on all of the other plots.  Any thoughts?  I know that `geom_vline`, `geom_hline`, and `geom_abline` will all appear on all of the facets, but I'm not sure what makes them unique.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have specified `type='E'` in your `line` data.frame. If you want to have this line on type `A,B,C,D`, then create a `data.frame` with the types on which you want the line to display

```
xl    = c( 4,  1)
yl    = c( 1,  4)
type =rep(LETTERS[1:4], each=2)
line2 = data.frame(x=xl,y=yl,type)

ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~type) +
   geom_line(data = line2)
```

You could also use `annotate`, which means you don't specify a data.frame, but pass the x and y values directly

```
ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~type) +
  annotate(geom='line', x=xl,y=yl)
```

Both create

[image]

Comment: You may even omit the type column completely, i.e. `line2 = data.frame(x=xl,y=yl)`. The line will  be the same across all panels then...

Comment: I have this same problem, but this solution no longer works: "Error: You're passing a function as global data.
Have you misspelled the `data` argument in `ggplot()`"

Comment: This still works for me, so @AdrianMartin must have stumbled upon some other issues when he could not make it work.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use geom_abline(...) as follows:

```
x    <-  c( 1,  3,  1,  3,  2,  4,  2,  4)
y    <-  c( 1,  3,  2,  4,  1,  3,  2,  4)
type <-  c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D")
data <-  data.frame(x,y,type)

int   <- c(5,5,5,5)
slope <- c(-1,-1,-1,-1)
type  <- c("A","B","C","D")
ref   <- data.frame(int, slope, type)
ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~type, scales="free") +
  geom_abline(data = ref, aes(intercept=int, slope=slope), color="red", size=2)
```

Which produces this:
[image]

Comment: I might have made my reproducible example a bit too simple; my actual code actually has more than just two points.  I should have added a third point to illustrate my problem.  Regardless, your answer definitely solves the question as I submitted it.