# One regression through multiple facets in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, lm

I am trying to fit a linear regression (9 of them actually) through a figure that has 20 facets.  Every time I fit the regression (using geom_smooth using method = lm), it fits 20 lines, one through each facet, however I would like the one line for each ReefSpecies combination to go through all 20 facets.

Here is my figure:

[Similar Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KmGk.jpg)

Here is what I have so far:

```
Biomass <- c(20, 10, 5, 4, 5, 7, 8, 22, 13, 13, 15, 18, 2, 5, 7, 10)
Season <- c("Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Fall")
Year <- c("1", "2", "3", "4")
ReefSpecies <- c("Admiral Ma", "Jaap Mf", "Grecian Ma", "Alligator Mf", "Jaap Mf", "Grecian Ma", "Alligator Mf", "Admiral Ma", "Grecian Ma", "Alligator Mf", "Admiral Ma", "Jaap Mf", "Alligator Mf", "Admiral Ma", "Jaap Mf","Grecian Ma")
Seasonal <- data.frame(Biomass, Season, Year, ReefSpecies)

testp <- ggplot(data = Seasonal, aes(x = Season, y = Biomass, group =        ReefSpecies, fill = ReefSpecies, colour = ReefSpecies))
testp <- testp + geom_point(stat = "identity", position="identity", inherit.aes = TRUE)
testp <- testp + facet_grid(. ~ Year, scales="fixed")
testp <- testp + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
testp <- testp + theme(panel.margin.x = unit(0, "lines"))
testp <- testp + theme(legend.position = "top")
testp
```

Comment: Please make your question reproducible.

Comment: In this vein, provide a bit of data so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: the ggplotGrob stuff and all the theme elements are not relevant to your question, and just make the post difficult on the eyes. The stuff inside `geom_point()` is also unnecessary. 
I suggest that whatever line you're using to fit the regression (stat_smooth or something?), that you specifically set the `group` aesthetic inside that layer. Note how in your initial `ggplot()` call, you're setting grouping and coloring aesthetics that will be inherited by all other layers unless you specify otherwise. you could add something like `+geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(group=1))`

Comment: Edited to add a small mock dataset! Thanks!

Comment: @Matt74 Hi Matt, I have tried using geom_smooth or stat_smooth - these just fit a regression line for each individual facet. I would like the regression line to incorporate all 20 facets

Comment: Do you want a regression line *across* all facets kind of like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31691313/2461552) or the same line within each facet like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20388435/adding-a-geom-line-to-all-facets-in-a-facet-wrap-plot-in-r)

Comment: [This question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673074/how-do-i-place-an-identical-smooth-on-each-facet-of-a-ggplot2-object) may be closely related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments, you do **not** want to [place an identical smooth on each facet of a ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673074/how-do-i-place-an-identical-smooth-on-each-facet-of-a-ggplot2-object) (which you can do by [setting the faceting variable to `NULL` in the smooth](https://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/12/03/ggplot2-overplotting-in-a-faceted-scatterplot/).

What you **do** want is to have a single regression across all facets. I think this isn't possible without some hacking [like that shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690007/ggplot-drawing-line-between-points-across-facets/31691313#31691313). You could try that.

But instead, I'd recommend stepping back to consider why you want to do it and what the smooth means. Perhaps it means facets aren't the right choice? In that case, you might consider defining a `Time` variable that accounts for seasons across years and regress on that (without facets).

An example (with tweaked data, because your example data does not have more than one observation per year):

```
Year <- sort(rep(Year, 4))
Seasonal <- data.frame(Biomass, Season, Year, ReefSpecies)
Seasonal$Time <- interaction(Season, Year)

ggplot(Seasonal, aes( Time,  Biomass, color=ReefSpecies)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(group=ReefSpecies), method="lm")
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the bad wording.  In your figure I would want 4 regression lines, one for each ReefSpecies combination that would cross the 4 facets

Comment: @aosmith The first link seems to be what I want, but I would fibbing if I told you I knew what was going on in that code.

Comment: Ok, the first link from @aosmith comment on Question? That is, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690007/ggplot-drawing-line-between-points-across-facets/31691313#31691313

Comment: Thx. Sorry for misunderstanding, perhaps rephrase the question to make crystal clear? The second sentence is a bit long although rereading it I see your meaning.

Comment: But, ultimately you want the seasons to have different meanings within each year? I don't think there's a way to do that within ggplot _and_ with facets without hacking via `gtable` or similar as in the linked answer.

Comment: This actually is perfect, I can just make time as a specific year so it can say something like Summer 2012, etc.  Thanks for all the help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. PS you can accept my answer. Or write your own with the code you end up using.